# Trying to make a function to handle AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, afnetworking

I'm trying to make a function that I'll call to handle the AFNetworking JSON parse.

Here is my code:

```
- (int)startParseWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)incomingParameters andUrlAdress:(NSString*)urlAdress;
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *parameters = incomingParameters;
    [manager POST:urlAdress parameters:parameters success:^

     (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSString *recivedErr = responseObject[@"error"];
         _errValue = [recivedErr intValue];

        NSLog(@"JSON: %d", _errValue);
     }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];

    return _errValue; 
}
```

I want the function to return 0 or 1, then I'll know if there is an error or not.
Right now it always return 0.

When I try to return in the success block I get a compiler error.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: That is because the success block is executed async.

Comment: so i should i return that int?

Comment: No, you should call a method from that block and not rely on the return mehtod. Since your function will exit (and return) before the success block is called.

Comment: can you please write a little example?

Answer (score 0):

The succes block is handled async so you should just call a method in the block:

```
- (void)startParseWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)incomingParameters andUrlAdress:(NSString*)urlAdress {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *parameters = incomingParameters;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [manager POST:urlAdress parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


         NSString *recivedErr = responseObject[@"error"];
        [weakSelf didReceiveResponse:[recivedErr integerValue];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

-(void)didReceiveResponse:(NSInteger)status {
}
```

Comment: You can't thats is the issue. The success block is executed after you method is already finished. The call the server is handled asynchronously.

Comment: ok.. so i cant build a function that i can call from another classes?
i have a lot of server request in my app so i want to build a JasonParser class that will handle it all..

Comment: Use blocks as callback just like `AFNetworking` then you don't need to return any value. You could just use `AFNetworking`s `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` in some class which is accessible from  every where in your project.

Comment: Ps it JSON not Jason!